# Difference between form_for , form_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the difference between form_for and form_tag? Is anything different for form_remote_for and form_remote_tag?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You would use form_for for a specific model,

```
<% form_for @person do |f| %> # you can use f here

    First name: <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
    Last name : <%= f.text_field :last_name %>

<% end %>
```

Form_tag create  basic form,

```
<%= form_tag '/person' do -%>
  <%= text_field_tag "person", "first_name" %>
<% end -%>
```

Answer (score 53):

`form_for` prefers, as its first arg, an activerecord object; it allows to easily make a create or edit form (to use it in a "new" view you should create an empty instance in controller, like:

```
def new
  @foo = Foo.new
end
```

It also passes a form variable to the block, so that you don't have to repeat the model name within the form itself. it's the preferred way to write a model related form.

`form_tag` just creates a form tag (and of course silently prepare an antiforgery hidden field, like `form_for`); it's best used for non-model forms (I actually only use it for simple search forms or the like).

<del>Similarly, `form_remote_for` and `form_remote_tag` are suited for model related forms and not model related forms respectively but, instead of ending in a standard http method (GET, POST...), they call an ajax method.</del>

All this and far more are available for you to enjoy in the [FormHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) <del>and [PrototypeHelper](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper.html)</del> reference pages.

**EDIT** 2012-07-13

`Prototype` has been removed from `rails` long ago, and remote forms have completely changed. Please refer to the first link, with reguard to the `:remote` option of both `form_for` and `form_tag`.

Comment: @WowBow you're right; after all, this answer is quite old, and Prototype has been removed from rails long ago. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: What does it mean that `form_for` "prefers" an ActiveRecord object?

Comment: @shiggity: it also accepts a symbol or string, of course. But given an ActiveRecord object, it does the right thing.

Answer (score 4):

These should be similar:

```
<% form_for @person do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
<% end %>
```

and:

```
<%= form_tag '/person' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag "person[name]" %>
<% end %>
```

If you want to submit the same params to the controller, you would have to define this explicitly.

Comment: Short and precise.
[Beautiful expiation]