# HAML form_tag problems with dropdown menue

Tags: haml

```
%h2 Your "followers":

- form_tag twitter_path do |f|
  = f.select{:name => "dropdown"}
    - for follower in @followers
      %option{:value => follower['id']}= h follower['name']

  = f.submit_tag "Who leaves comments?"
```

How do you properly format this HAML? Its returning a Syntax Error.

Answer (score 1):

You're using HAML syntaxe inside Ruby code here:

```
= f.select{:name => "dropdown"}
```

The brace `{` is interpreted as the begining of a Ruby block (like in `array.map { ... }`), because everything after the `=` or `-` prefix in HAML is evaluated as Ruby code.

Also, you're using the `form_for` syntax while using the `form_tag` method (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349348/difference-between-form-for-form-tag)).
The `form_tag` method doesn't provide a form object `f`.
You should use the `select_tag` method from [FormTagHelper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html) instead, along with a [FormOptionsHelper method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html):

```
- form_tag twitter_path do
  = select_tag "dropdown", options_from_collection_for_select(@followers, "id", "name")
  = submit_tag "Who leaves comments?"
```