# What's the difference between form_for and form_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

And when would you decide to use one or the other? I am just learning rails so I know this is a pretty simple question, but it wasn't clear from the API.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between form_for , form_tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349348/difference-between-form-for-form-tag)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you want to update or create a specific model, use form_for.

```
<% form_for @user do |f| %>
```

When you want to have a normal html form that you can pass options to that's not backed by a model, use form_tag.

Answer (score 0):

You would use **form_for** for a specific **model**

**form_tag** create basic form