# Difference between form_for and form_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, form-for

I used [this gem](https://github.com/curtis/honeypot-captcha) in my application, but I'm not sure the difference between the different implementation options for the gem:

- form_for
- form_tag with block
- form_tag without block

Can anyone clarify?  I understand that `form_for` is used when you wish to interact with a model, but what about the other two?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between form\_for , form\_tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349348/difference-between-form-for-form-tag)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The differences are subtle, but important. `form_for` is a more advanced tool that yields an object you use to generate your form elements:

```
<% form_for(@foo) do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field(:bar) %>
<% end %>
```

The `form_tag` method is much more primitive and just emits a tag. If you want to put things inside of the `<form>` tag that's emitted, you put things inside the block:

```
<% form_tag do %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:bar, 'bar_value') %>
<% end %>
```

Note that the `form_for` method handles grabbing values from your model, and will at least try to route the form to the appropriate action. With `form_tag` you are responsible for everything as it makes no assumptions about what you're doing.

Answer (score 4):

One uses model binding and the other doesn't

Comment: Can you elaborate on what model binding is?

Comment: @mbigras afaik model binding is when you have a form, (with for example a persons name in it) and it automatically gets populated into a "person" object by rails (or other frameworks) on submit.

Comment: as you can see in tadmans example the form_for is "scoped" to the object @ foo (which is why you only need to specify the attribute name, bar, unlike in the form_tag example).     This form_for tag also supports reads/writes/updates on that @foo object out of the box

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is only one simple difference. form_tag without a block will only generate a  html element for you. When you use form with a a block it will also create the form closing tag .

In example:

```
<% form_tag("/comments") %>
```

will result in

```
<form action="/comments">
```

Where

```
<%= form_tag("/comments") do %>
  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

will generate

```
<form action="/comments">
  <input type="sumbit" />
</form>
```