# Button event trigger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having trouble understanding as how do you trigger specific button event when using Ruby on Rails.  For example I have a mini form inside a table as so (View side of MVC):

```
<%= form_tag do %>
<% if student.floor_pref == '1st' %>
    <td><%= select_tag 'room', options_for_select(@first_floor.map { |value| [value,value]}, @selected_room) %></td>
<% end %>
<% if student.floor_pref == '2nd' %>
    <td><%= select_tag 'room', options_for_select(@second_floor.map { |value| [value,value]}, @selected_room) %></td>
<% end %>
<% if student.floor_pref == '3rd' %>
    <td><%= select_tag 'room', options_for_select(@third_floor.map { |value| [value,value]}, @selected_room) %></td>
<% end %>

<td><%= submit_tag 'Update' %></td>
<% end %>
```

How do I tell the controller that when the Update button is clicked inside the view to for example execute this code:

```
a = Student.find(3)

a.room_number = '2105'
a.save
```

Answer (score 2):

Your button should be triggering a post-back to the server. You need to define an action in your controller, a route to reach that action, and set your forms `action` attribute to that route. Your action can then update the models and respond with a success or error message.

Comment: Can you show me how this is done using this example?  I am new to Ruby and asked this before but no one can seem to help.

Comment: Which part? I gave you three steps: Define an action in your controller, create a route, update your `<form>` tag to include an `action="..."` attribute to reach your route. This is *extremely* basic Rails coding, and literally every tutorial written will tell you how to do this.

Comment: All three parts really.  I've used scaffolding to build my MVC and besides just declaring variables that run a query and return results inside a controller I really don't understand much beyond that point.  I've gone through couple of tutorials and they all show the same thing which really doesn't help me with this.

Comment: This is just basic example that is a part of bigger problem that I'm trying to figure out.  I feel that if I can get this working I can build on that and use the stuff I learned from tutorials to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

u should specify a route(a controller action to which the data is to be submitted) in the form tag. refer http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/form_tag for more details. considering that ur action is for 'edit' action from students controller and that data is to be posted to 'update', the view can be defined as

```
<%= form_tag student_path(@student), :method => :put do %>
  ...
  <$= submit_tag 'Update' %>
```

and in the 'update' method, u can write the code to update student with the received params. I think u need to study basic rails functioning since it will save u time in future. u can refer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html Also, prefer using form_for rather than form_tag.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  In the form tag could I specify it as following:  <%= form_tag :controller => 'students', :action => 'update' do %>  ?  Only reason I'm asking this way is because I'm still learning the Ruby syntax and this makes more sense to me.  Thanks again.

Comment: yes. please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540291/difference-between-form-for-and-form-tag for difference between form_for and form_tag.

Comment: Sweet, that got me somewhere. Thanks! Data is updating fine now but the action I call in the controller as shown above 'update' doesn't have a view so when I click the update button it actually updates the room column but after that it displays the "Template is missing" page.  Is there a way that I can tell it after it perform the 'update' action to just go back to the 'index' page?  Thanks again!

Comment: u can redirect to any page if the object is created/updated successfully. check point 6.9 on rails guides for an example.

Comment: I see, thanks.  I'm going over that guide atm.  Thanks again for your help, it helped me solve the big problem I was originally having.  Now the web app works 100%