# Rails helper form_for passes a nil:NilClass parameter to the block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, helper

Browsing the excellent [Rails tutorial by Michael Hartl](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) (Chapter 8), I'm trying to use the `form_tag` helper provided by Rails in my (Haml) view. The form passed by `form_tag` to the block has value `nil`, which I guess is not the intended use, since it prevents to generate fields in the form. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Here the haml code:

```
= form_tag(sessions_path) do |f|
  = # f.label :email # undefined method `label' for nil:NilClass
  = f.class.name     # NilClass
= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f|
  = f.label :email   # Email
  = f.class.name     # ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
```

Here the HTML that the **first part** of it (`form_tag`) generates:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/sessions" method="post"><div style="display:none"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="c72gY3kuFKTFxNerFWT5fH1n63cp9U8Wj0+UBTllqPQ=" /></div>

nil
</form>
```

On the contrary, the `form_for` have the expected behavior.

I could not find answers searching on the internet: In the [RailsCast 270 about Authentication](http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1)  (around 3:30), the video shows code that seems similar to mine. I did not find related answers when searching with such keywords as `form_tag`, `NilClass` or `haml` on Stackoverflow and Google.

Would anyone have a clue about what I did wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540291/difference-between-form-for-and-form-tag) to understand the difference between `form_for` and `form_tag`.

In the Railscasts episode you mentioned, the code looks like this:

```
= form_tag(sessions_path) do
  = label_tag :email
  = text_field_tag :email, params[:email]
```

Which is not similar to your code!

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I missed that!