# trouble converting from form_for to form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

How do I convert this to form_tag? This code is basically from RoR Tutorial by Michael Hartl Chapter 8 Exercise 1

```
<% provide(:title, "Sign in") %>
<h1>Sign in</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

    <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried something like this

```
<% provide(:title, "Sign in") %>
<h1>Sign in</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <% form_tag sessions_path, methods=> :post do %>
        <%= label_tag 'email' %><br />
        <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email], :placeholder => "Email" %>

        <%= label_tag 'password' %><br />
        <%= password_field_tag :password %>

        <%= submit_tag 'Sign in' %>
    <% end -%>
    <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

But its not displaying the form at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add an equal sign:

```
<%= form_tag sessions_path, methods=> :post do %>
```

However, I wonder why you want to switch to `form_tag`. `form_for` has many advantages in my opinion e.g. the form builder.

Comment: oh ok. that's great then. 'cause it was just an exercise. Thanks for the opinion, I'll stick to form_for :)

Comment: Okay. Just want to add that it should display at least something when you add the equal sign at the beginning of the form_tag method. This was a change made in Rails 3. In Rails 2 this should work without the equal sign, also. Could you please mark this answer as accepted if I answered you question completely? Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I am also trying to convert to the form_tag.

Correct Syntax

```
<%= form_tag sessions_path, :method => 'post' do %>
```

Incorrect Syntax

```
<% form_tag sessions_path, methods=> :post do %>
```

You need to add an '=' to the opening embed tag, change methods to :method, and :post to 'post'

The reasons for using [form_for vs form_tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349348/difference-between-form-for-form-tag), are discussed in another stack overflow thread.

Another change that needs to be made is in the sessions_controller.rb.  The hash passed back wont be recognized by the controller, as it is set up to accept a hash from form_for method.  You must remove the first [:session] hash in two lines.  Your sessions_controller.rb should look like this,

```
def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
        sign_in user
        redirect_to user
    else
        flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination' 
        render 'new'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The next will be the code for the Tutorial (Michael Hartl 3.2) Chapter 8 . Exercise 1

```
<% provide(:title, "Sign in") %>
<h1>Sign in</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset3">

        <%= form_tag sessions_path, :method => 'post' do %>
          <%= label_tag 'email', 'Email' %>
          <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email], :placeholder => "Email" %>
          <%= label_tag 'password', 'Password' %>
         <%= password_field_tag :password %>
      <br>
      <%= submit_tag "Sign In" , :class=> "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
    <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
</div>
```