# Search form not redirecting to Search View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I'm integrating ElasticSearch in my Rails application, based on this [tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/full-text-search-rails-elasticsearch/?utm_content=bufferf0483&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer)

Unlike the tutorial demo app, I'm not implementing my search form on the search View, but I'm implementing the search form in a shared layout:

```
app/views/shared/_header.html.erb
...
<%= form_for search_path, method: :get do |f| %>
  <%= f.label "Search for" %>
  <%= text_field_tag :q, params[:q] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Go", name: nil %>
<% end %>
```

the route for search_path looks like this:

```
  get 'search', to: 'search#search'
```

the search#search action looks like this:

```
app/controllers/search_controller.rb
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def search
    if params[:q].nil?
      @publications = []
    else
      @publications = Publication.search params[:q]
    end
  end
end
```

However, when I type a search term in the search form and press the 'Go' button, I'm not going to the search page (app/views/search/search.html.erb) as I expected.

I just stay on the homepage of my application.

Does anyone know why the the 'Go' button of my search form is not sending me to the search view template?

Thanks for your help,

Anthony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
<%= form_tag(search_path, method: :get) %>
<% end %>
```

read about [form_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag)

Actually form_for used for a specific model, but form_tag used for create basic form, See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349348/difference-between-form-for-form-tag)

Comment: Hi Mohamed, you make my day. The search form is redirecting to the search view template now.