# Passing Custom Form Values to a Custom Controller Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

In Rails, I have a custom controller action that needs to accept some parameters from a form:

```
def update_ordid

# Get the active exchange
@exchange = Exchange.find(params[:id])

# Decide which order ID field to update
active_order_field = params[:ordfld]    

# Save the order ID
order_id = params[:ordid]

if active_order_field == 1 then
  @exchange.order_id_1 = order_id
else
  @exchange.order_id_2 = order_id
end

@active_exchange.save
respond_with(@exchange)

end
```

Because these parameters aren't actual data fields in the exchange table, I would typically invoke the action by using a link such as:

```
link_to "Update Order ID", update_ordid_exchange(ordfld: value_from_form, ordid: value_from_form), :method => :post
```

Because in this case the value of these parameters needs to be populated by user input, I created the following form to pass the data:

```
<%= form_for(@exchange, url: update_ordid_exchange_path) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :ordid, "Order ID" %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :ordid, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

<% if @isrequestor == true %>
  <%f.hidden_field :ordfld, :value => "1" %>
 <% else %>
  <%f.hidden_field :ordfld, :value => "2" %>
<% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary"  %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

When I attempt to render this form, I receive the error: **undefined method `ordid' for #**

When researching this issue, I found that I could be able to do this by changing the text_field line to:

```
<%= f.text_field_tag :ordid, class: "form-control" %>
```

While this resolves the initial error, it throws a new error: **undefined method `text_field_tag' for #**

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `_tag` suffix is not used for `form_for`.

Comment: Ok, is there something else I should be doing to allow the form to pass the parameters?

Comment: can you post your whole error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `form_for` since your form elements doesn't represent the attributes of a model. use `form_tag` instead

```
<%= form_tag(update_ordid_exchange_path, :method => :patch) do%>
  <div class="field">
    <%= label_tag "Order ID" %><br>
    <%= text_field_tag :ordid, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
  <% if @isrequestor == true %>
   <%= hidden_field_tag :ordfld, "1" %>
  <% else %>
   <%= hidden_field_tag :ordfld, "2" %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= submit_tag "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary"  %>
  </div>
<%end%>
```

Documentation [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag)

[form_tag vs form_for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349348/difference-between-form-for-form-tag)

[hidden_field_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/hidden_field_tag)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this code but am getting the error: No route matches [POST] "/exchanges/2/update_ordid" Do I need to modify anything in the controller as well?

Comment: My route is: resources :exchanges do
    patch :update_ordid, on: :member
  end

Comment: By default, form submit will be a post request. Since you have defined the path for patch, you have to specify the method explicitly in form_tag

Comment: Thanks! This gets me to the same point as the first answer. There must still be something wrong with this line: <% hidden_field_tag :ordfld, :value => "1" %> as the value of "1" is not being passed to the controller.

Comment: According to the documentation of hidden_field_tag, value is a second argument. Not a hash

Comment: After checking the documentation, I've changed it to <% hidden_field_tag :ordfld, "1" %> still no luck though. (Tried it with and without quotes around "1")

Comment: Didn't notice the missing "=" before `hidden_field_tag`. updated my answer

Comment: Thanks so much for your patience, everything has been resolved!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit new to this myself, but I believe it's because you're calling "text_field_tag" from a form_for instead of form_tag builder object. Try just leaving off the form for object as such:

```
<%= text_field_tag :ordid, class: "form-control" %>
```

Comment: i guess in this approach, though you have resolved it, its not right approach because `:ordid` is a column in your table and its better to use `<%= f.text_field :ordid %>` in your form

Comment: This gets it very close to working right, though there must still be an issue with the hidden fields as :ordfld is not passing it's value to the controller. <% hidden_field_tag :ordfld, :value => "1" %> (Rahul, :ordid is actually NOT a column in the table.)

Comment: oh, if its a not a column in database, then this would do good. You can bind `form_for` only with columns present in database.