# error using form_for between 2 controllers (params is missing or empty)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The error I'm getting is:

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing in CampaignsController#create
param is missing or the value is empty: campaign
```

my routes:

```
resources :users, except: [:destroy] do
  post 'add_email', on: :member
end

resources :campaigns, only: [:create, :destroy, :index] do
  get 'status'
end
```

my modal that appears in campaigns#index

```
<%= form_for add_email_user_path(@user) do |f| %>
 <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: 'Your email address', class: 'input-lg form-control', autofocus: true %>
 <%= f.button 'Continue', class: 'btn btn-success', 'data-disable-with' => "Saving <i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i>".html_safe %>
<% end %>
```

campaigns_controller:

```
def index
  @campaigns = current_user.campaigns.all
  @new_campaign = current_user.campaigns.new
  @user = current_user
end

private

def campaign_params
  params.require(:campaign).permit(:keyword)
end
```

users_controller:

```
def add_email
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(setup_params)
    redirect_to campaigns_path, notice: 'Thank you for adding your email!'
  else
    redirect_to :back, alert: 'Unable to save your email'
  end
end

private

def setup_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:email)
end
```

logs:

```
Started POST "/campaigns" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-03-27 11:14:30 +0100
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by CampaignsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"1fdQs7J5vvEV/b29thmAx5udaTc7ushkDAutJPWSESc=", "/users/7/add_email"=>{"email"=>"sebe@asm.com"}, "follow"=>"yes", "button"=>""}
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 7]]
Completed 400 Bad Request in 85ms

ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: campaign):
  app/controllers/campaigns_controller.rb:42:in `campaign_params'
  app/controllers/campaigns_controller.rb:6:in `create'


  Rendered /Users/sja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/sja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/sja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/sja/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/actionpack-4.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (26.3ms)
```

so what I'm trying to do is allow the user to add their email (which appears in a modal on campaigns index, but for some reason I get that the campaign param is missing. Campaign belongs_to user.

Comment: in your campaign controller new method define `@campaign = Campaign.new` and in user controller new method `@user = User.new`

Comment: @Sontya, what's the point in your comment?

Comment: @sja , post logs for the action that fails.

Comment: ok I've updated with the logs @rmagnum2002

Comment: This is the error only, I need logs from the begging of request, from the point you push the Continue button in add_email form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you are trying to add an email to user, your logs show somehow that this action calls create action from campaings, and params are all wrong, I suspect this is because you are using:

`form_for`

when you should use:

`form_tag`

using `form_for` will look for a resource and since you are in `/campaings` it will interpret this action as a post to campaigns.

Or if you want to use `form_for` you should add user to the form:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: add_email_user_path(@user) do |f| %>
```

see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349348/difference-between-form-for-form-tag) for differences between `form_for` and `form_tag`

Also, you are just updating your user with the email, so you might use the default update action form users controller and remove the `add_email` method.

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.email_field :email, placeholder: 'Your email address', class: 'input-lg form-control', autofocus: true %>
  <%= f.submit 'Continue', class: 'btn btn-success', 'data-disable-with' => "Saving <i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i>".html_safe %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: form_for @user, add_email_user_path(@user) returns no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Comment: you should specify the `add_email_user_path(@user) ` as url in the form

Comment: No route matches [PATCH] "/users/7/add_email" is what I get then. If I add the add_email.html.erb file the submit doesn't work

Comment: Because you route says `post 'add_email', on: :member`, if you''ll use `put 'add_email', on: :member` it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Write

```
form_for [:add_email, @user], method: :post do |f|
```

or, the longer version:

```
form_for @user, url: add_email_user_path(@user), method: :post do |f|
```