# Getting Params from raw HTML components in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making an input form whose features don't fit so nicely into the general `form_for` template rails provides. I figured I would write my own HTML mimicking the html output of `form_for`, but embedded with other `form_for` elements.

For fields I could use the rails framework for I did. For the others I made hidden fields to store what was going to Rails, and regular input fields whose values I manipulated with JavaScript to put into the hidden fields.

This is one such field:

```
State:<br>
<input type="text" class = "state name_input administrative_area_level_1">
<div class="field">
  <input type="hidden" name="address[state]" id="state">
</div>
```

When I send the value of the hidden field to the console, I get a good response:

```
state 37
```

Which means the state field holds the value 37. Perfect.

Except that when I try to make my model, the params come in empty:

```
"state"=>"",
```

I do have one field that works that isn't hidden:

```
Street:<br><input type="text" id="street" name="address[street]">
```

So I changed the state input type to number, which is what it would be if it weren't hidden, but same result. Why can't rails find my param?

Comment: I think if your structure does not fit the form_for helper, you should probably reconsider your structure... I haven't run in any situations where there's a need to hardcode these forms. Can you give a use-case or provide relevant model / controller code?

Answer (score 0):

You can show post more detail. I can't understand 100% things you do because you write pretty simple. But i guess that you need test params name is address[state] but it's not only state becase if only state of course it nil. 
if html of you rendered same up then i suggest you should put one debug in controller to see params return controller when submit form.
For example: in controller you add line:

```
logger.debug params
```

to see right params that form send.

Answer (score 0):

If your form is not tied directly to a object model, it might be difficult to use the form_for helper. In those cases you should use form_tag helper. Read more about form_tag helper [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#dealing-with-basic-forms).

Refer this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349348/difference-between-form-for-form-tag) answer for the difference between form_for and form_tag helpers.

Hope this helps.